# Renaming public_html for main domain to subdomain which is development website

Tags: ftp, webserver

In CPanel I created a subdomain `test.mydomain.com` under my main domain `mydomain.com`. Both domains have magento websites. The contents of `mydomain.com` are stored in `public_html` and the contents of `test.mydomain.com` are stored in folder `test`, both in the same directory.

I copied them to my local PC. Also they are very very large sites with 30.000 products.

I would like to make the test environment live. Is it okay to change `public_html` to `public_html_old` and rename the folder `test` to `public_html` in FTP client (for example filezilla)? This will help me not to move large files and folders across.

Comment: Can you explain the situation a little bit more? What's magento? Is this a live site that you're trying to make a copy of via filezilla?

Comment: @slm both are live sites. I just want to swap files between test.mydomain.com (test folder) and mydomain.com (public_html folder) these two folders are in the same directory anyway. What if I just change the folder name instead of moving files or copying them.

Comment: From what you've explained it seems like you should be able to just change the names. Realize when changing these names that you'll be essentially breaking the mydomin.com site.